# Rolling average across several columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas

```
import random
random.sample(range(1, 100), 10)
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": random.sample(range(1, 100), 10), 
                   "B":random.sample(range(1, 100), 10),
                  "C":random.sample(range(1, 100), 10)})
df["D"]="need_to_calc"
df
```

[image]

I need the value of Column D, Row 9 to equal the average of the block of cells from rows 6 through 8 across columns A through C.    I want to do this for all rows.

I am not sure how to do this in a single pythonic action.  Instead I have hacky temporary columns and ugly nonsense.

Is there a cleaner way to define this column without temporary tables?

Comment: @liliscent Thanks, but i need to do that window calculation for each row in D.  I just showed row 9 as an example.

Comment: @AshishAcharya Got it almost right, but deleted the answer :/ You can do it with `df.rolling(3).mean().mean(1).shift()`

Comment: @liliscent yeah, that worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
means = df.rolling(3).mean().shift(1)
df['D'] = (means['A'] + means['B'] + means['C'])/3
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C          D
0  43  57  15        NaN
1  86  34  68        NaN
2  40  12  78        NaN
3  97  24  54  48.111111
4  90  42  10  54.777778
5  34  54  98  49.666667
6  98  36  31  55.888889
7  16   5  24  54.777778
8  35  53  67  44.000000
9  80  66  37  40.555556
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it so:

```
df["D"]= (df.sum(axis=1).rolling(window=3, min_periods=3).sum()/9).shift(1)
```

Example:

```
    A   B   C             D
0  62  89  12  need_to_calc
1  44  13  63  need_to_calc
2  28  21  54  need_to_calc
3  93  93   4  need_to_calc
4  95  84  42  need_to_calc
5  68  68  35  need_to_calc
6   3  92  56  need_to_calc
7  13  88  83  need_to_calc
8  22  37  23  need_to_calc
9  64  58   5  need_to_calc
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C          D
0  62  89  12        NaN
1  44  13  63        NaN
2  28  21  54        NaN
3  93  93   4  42.888889
4  95  84  42  45.888889
5  68  68  35  57.111111
6   3  92  56  64.666667
7  13  88  83  60.333333
8  22  37  23  56.222222
9  64  58   5  46.333333
```